# iPhone/iPad Status bar overlapping on app's header

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I am using worklight 6.2 Consumer Edition on WAS Liberty Profile 8.5.5.1 Server. I am using jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 to develop UI. When I install app on iPhone/iPad, status bar of phone is hiding some part of my app's header.

How can I fix this issue (if its an issue)?

Comment: you have to check your JQueryMobile implementation, nothing related to WL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine in a default [new app with jQuery Mobile](http://i62.tinypic.com/2a8mheg.png) that was generated by Worklight Studio. As you can see, the status does not overlap the text.

You can also take a look at the [Worklight Starter with jQuery Mobile edition](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/WorklightStarter_jQueryMobile.zip), that also works on iOS w/out the status bar covering the top of app. Compare your CSS.

You need to provide a screen shot of what you're seeing, as well as provide a sample application where you are experiencing it. This issue originates from your code. Provide code.

One possible solution would be to add some `margin-top` to whichever element is at the top of your applicaiton's HTML.

Comment: Accepting your answer but I went through the code of demo app which you referenced and I found that status bar is still overlapping the header. However, it is handled in css by applying padding and margin on buttons in header and that's why they appears to be separate.